# spring mvc url cannot read quotation mark

Tags: java, string, spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem on this link: `http://localhost:8080/reg?lok=34a4a3s3a3a`

And I've created the following method:

```
@RequestMapping("/reg?lok={lok}"), method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirm(@RequestParam("lok") String lok) {
   ....
   return "index";
}
```

I can't get this value from url after lok=....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the query string variable from `@RequestMapping` annotation.  Spring MVC will recognize it as a `@RequestParam` automatically.  And also define the `@RequestMapping` attributes as `name=value`.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/reg",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String myRequest(@RequestParam("lok") String lok){
    System.out.println(lok);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why there is a whitelabel page with info "lok" not found as parameter, but it shows me printed value of lok in terminal ?

Comment: ok, then you can read `lok` parameter, but, are you waiting for `lok` parameter at index page? also you can share the index page to see how are you reading it.  One additional question how is the `lok` parameter passed to index page?